# Somers D differences between R and SAS and within R

Tags: r, sas, logistic-regression

I am new to both R and SAS. I want to calculate somers D, following the logistic regression.my dataframe(vac1) is combination of Titer and Protection.

```
> vac1=structure(list(Titer = c(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.51, 0.9, 0.9, 2.86,1.95,2.71, 2.56, 2.71, 3.01, 2.71, 2.41, 2.11, 1.95, 2.26, 2.71, 2.56, 2.41, 2.56, 1.95, 1.81, 2.26, 2.11, 1.81, 1.95, 1.95, 1.34, 2.56, 2.26, 2.26, 2.11, 2.41, 2.71, 2.56, 1.65, 1.95, 1.51, 1.95,1.81, 1.81, 1.81, 1.95, 2.11, 2.86,2.41, 1.95, 2.56, 2.71, 2.71,2.41, 1.81, 2.41, 1.65, 1.81, 2.11, 2.11, 1.81, 1.81,2.26, 2.41,1.65, 2.56, 2.71, 2.11, 1.81), Protection = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 1, 0, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)), .Names = c("Titer","Protection"), row.names = c(NA, -67L), class = "data.frame").
```

my logistic regression formula is.

```
> logit=glm(Protection~Titer, data=vac1, family=binomial(link="logit")).
```

the resulting predicted probalities from logit model is combined with original Protection data from vac1 dataframe and created vac4 dataframe.

```
> vac4=cbind(vac1$Protection,logit$fit)
> colnames(vac4)=c("Protection","PredictedProb").
```

calculated somers D by 2 ways.

1.using InformationValue package

```
>library(InformationValue)
>somersD(actuals=vac4$Protection, predictedScores=vac4$PredictedProb
```

I got the value 0.733.

2.using function copied from a link
http://shashiasrblog.blogspot.in/2014/02/binary-logistic-regression-fast.html

```
    OptimisedConc=function(logit)
{
  Data = vac4 
  ones = Data[Data[,1] == 1,]
  zeros = Data[Data[,1] == 0,]
  conc=matrix(0, dim(zeros)[1], dim(ones)[1])
  disc=matrix(0, dim(zeros)[1], dim(ones)[1])
  ties=matrix(0, dim(zeros)[1], dim(ones)[1])
  for (j in 1:dim(zeros)[1])
  {
    for (i in 1:dim(ones)[1])
    {
      if (ones[i,2]>zeros[j,2])
      {conc[j,i]=1}
      else if (ones[i,2]<zeros[j,2])
      {disc[j,i]=1}
      else if (ones[i,2]==zeros[j,2])
      {ties[j,i]=1}
    }
  }
  Pairs=dim(zeros)[1]*dim(ones)[1]
  PercentConcordance=(sum(conc)/Pairs)*100
  PercentDiscordance=(sum(disc)/Pairs)*100
  PercentTied=(sum(ties)/Pairs)*100
  N<-length(logit$fit)
  gamma<-(sum(conc)-sum(disc))/Pairs
  Somers_D<-(sum(conc)-sum(disc))/(Pairs-sum(ties))
  k_tau_a<-2*(sum(conc)-sum(disc))/(N*(N-1))
  return(list("Percent Concordance"=PercentConcordance,
              "Percent Discordance"=PercentDiscordance,
              "Percent Tied"=PercentTied,
              "Pairs"=Pairs,
              "Gamma"=gamma,
              "Somers D"=Somers_D,
              "Kendall's Tau A"=k_tau_a))
}
OptimisedConc(logit).
```

Here i am getting the gamma and somers D values but are reversed compared to what i got it in SAS and the somers D value calculated by 2nd method in R and SAS is different from what i obtained it using the InformationValue package of R.  similarly kendalls tau is infinite showing in R and in SAS it is 0.38.

can anyone help where i am making mistake? thanking you.

Comment: How is this calculated in SAS?

Comment: PROC Logistic data=vac1;
model Protection(event='1') = Titer/expb ;
output out=pred p=phat lower=lcl upper=ucl
          predprob=(individual crossvalidate);
run;

Comment: That's all fine and well, but is the underlying math known to to community?

Comment: I could not find any formula in SAS document that how somersD is calculated under PROC LOGISTIC. However i could find formula for for somersD using PROC FREQ procedure [Link] ( https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/stat/chap28/sect20.htm).